# Css zoom-in effect on screen resize

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a zooming effect on image on screen resize that is working as on attached image example.

So first I want it to looks like the image was cut-out from the right side (but with remaining height), and then after I want to zoom-in image from all sides. Can someone suggest how can I create this effect?

I know for zooming in I should use:

```
transform:scale(1.5);
-ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want it to animate on screen resize, or just want the image to look like it's been cropped differently at different screen sizes? If the latter, look into CSS background-size and background-position. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to do with zoom-in effect, it's more about responsive design. I don't think there is a perfect solution here, it'll depend on the content you will have on your page and on the image you want to use as a background. Without any media query, you take a look at my solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/9htcmus7/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc placerat, risus vitae aliquet consequat, eros tortor tincidunt lacus, in mollis mi est id tellus. Nulla id odio nec tortor vestibulum suscipit non id metus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10vw 20vw;
  background-image: url(http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/mountain/mountain-04.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 25%;
}

.content {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 2;
  color: white;
  width: 25em;
  max-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: The background-position part is totally up to you and the image you want to use! First value is x-positioning, second y-positioning.

BTW, to avoid media queries, I used responsive units like vw (viewport width), percentages, background-size: cover, etc... It's always better than using pixels or fixed units, but never flawless so don't be afraid to use media queries if needed.

Comment: This is a great solution! Thanks for suggestion. I will edit it little bit, and add some special media queries, but that is it! Thanks!